# Javascript word count function not working if the text are generated in the textarea

Tags: javascript, function, events, textarea, addeventlistener

How to realtime reflect the word count of textarea. The below script works great for count characters (even non-English languages are OK). But the problem is that it won't work if the text is generated from the script itself. I had changed the event from "keyup" to "change" to "input", but none of them will work. they only work when typing in the textarea.

Anyone gives me some ideas?

```js
var outputCombo = document.getElementById("outputCombo");
var textInfo = document.getElementById("text-info ");

if (document.querySelector('input[name="radio_btn"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio_btn"]').forEach((elem, i) => {
    elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      outputCombo.value = "you pressed " + elem.value;

    });
  });
}



outputCombo.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var maxLength = 280;
  var strLength = outputCombo.value.replace(/[^\x00-\xff]/g, "01 ").length;
  var charRemain = (maxLength - strLength);
  if (charRemain < 0) {
    textInfo.innerHTML = '<span style="color: red; ">surpassed ' + charRemain + ' chracters</span>';
    outputCombo.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    textInfo.innerHTML = 'remaining: ' + charRemain;
    outputCombo.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" value="Instagram">
    <label>Instagram</label>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" value="Twitter"><label>Twitter</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<textarea class="form-control" id="outputCombo"></textarea>
<span id="text-info ">word count: </span>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fire the event manually once you set the value to `textarea`

```
outputCombo.value = "you pressed " + elem.value;
outputCombo.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I add your script for count into a function then use it when you change value of textarea like:

```js
var outputCombo = document.getElementById("outputCombo");
var textInfo = document.getElementById("text-info ");

if (document.querySelector('input[name="radio_btn"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio_btn"]').forEach((elem, i) => {
    elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      outputCombo.value = "you pressed " + elem.value;
      countTextArea();
    });
  });
}



outputCombo.addEventListener("input", function() {
  countTextArea();
});

function countTextArea() {
  var maxLength = 280;
  var strLength = outputCombo.value.replace(/[^\x00-\xff]/g, "01 ").length;
  var charRemain = (maxLength - strLength);
  if (charRemain < 0) {
    textInfo.innerHTML = '<span style="color: red; ">surpassed ' + charRemain + ' chracters</span>';
    outputCombo.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    textInfo.innerHTML = 'remaining: ' + charRemain;
    outputCombo.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }

}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" value="Instagram">
    <label>Instagram</label>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" value="Twitter"><label>Twitter</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<textarea class="form-control" id="outputCombo"></textarea>
<span id="text-info ">word count: </span>
```

Comment: No problem :), remember the best way for re-use your code it's create a function instead of use manually trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger an input event with `outputCombo.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))`

Here's the full code:

```
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" value="Instagram">
        <label>Instagram</label>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" value="Twitter"><label>Twitter</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<textarea class="form-control" id="outputCombo"></textarea>
<span id="text-info ">word count: </span>

<script type="text/javascript ">
    var outputCombo = document.getElementById("outputCombo");
    var textInfo = document.getElementById("text-info ");

    if (document.querySelector('input[name="radio_btn"]')) {
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio_btn"]').forEach((elem, i) => {
            elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
                outputCombo.value = "you pressed " + elem.value;

                // Here is the triggered event
                outputCombo.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))

            });
        });
    }



    outputCombo.addEventListener("input", function() {
        var maxLength = 280;
        var strLength = outputCombo.value.replace(/[^\x00-\xff]/g, "01 ").length;
        var charRemain = (maxLength - strLength);
        if (charRemain < 0) {
            textInfo.innerHTML = '<span style="color: red; ">surpassed ' + charRemain + ' chracters</span>';
            outputCombo.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        } else {
            textInfo.innerHTML = 'remaining: ' + charRemain;
            outputCombo.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }
    });
</script>
```